# How to create select option with autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to create a `select` with autocomplete but still cannot do this works. How could I do this ?

I'm trying.

```
function fillSelect(data) {
    //$('#usuarioSelected').empty();
    if (data['InvestidorMaster'].length > 0) {
        //$.each(data["InvestidorMaster"], function (i, cp) {
        //    $('#usuarioSelected').append('<option value="' + cp.id + '">' + cp.nome + '</option>');
        //});
       //fill select without autocomplete it works 

        //autocomplete
        var suggestions = [];
        $.each(data["InvestidorMaster"], function (i, cp) {
            suggestions.push({ 'value' : cp.id, 'label' : cp.nome});
        });
        $("#usuarioSelected").autocomplete({
            source: suggestions           
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems ambiguous, can you provide more of an example.

Comment: Or did you want to make a combobox: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your code does not have any functional errors, I have restructured your code:

```
function fillSelect(data) {
    var suggestions = [];

    if (data['InvestidorMaster'].length > 0) {
       $.each(data["InvestidorMaster"], function (i, cp) {
          $('#usuarioSelected').append('<option value="' + cp.id + '">' + cp.nome + '</option>');
       });


        $.each(data["InvestidorMaster"], function (i, cp) {
            suggestions.push({ 'value' : cp.id, 'label' : cp.nome});
        });

    }

    //Now initialize the autocomplete with the suggestions array
    $("#usuarioSelected").autocomplete({
        source: suggestions           
    });
}
```